# Alerts in K8s for Pod failing

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

I wanted to create alerts in Grafana for My Kubernetes Clusters.
I have configured Prometheus, Node exporter, Kube-Metrics, Alert Manager in my k8s Cluster.
I wanted to setup Alerting on Unschedulable or Failed Pods.

1. Cause of unschedulable or failed pods
2. Generating an alert after a while
3. Creating another alert to notify us when pods fail.
   Can You guide me how to achieve this??

Comment: Hi Sayali, it might be helpful https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html#kubernetes

Comment: Where exactly is the problem and what did you try?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the comment from [Suresh Vishnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8803619/suresh-vishnoi):

> it might be helpful [awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html#kubernetes](https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html#kubernetes)

yes, this could be very helpful. On this site you can find templates for [failed pods (not healthy)](https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html#rule-kubernetes-1-17):

> Pod has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.

```yaml
  - alert: KubernetesPodNotHealthy
    expr: min_over_time(sum by (namespace, pod) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Unknown|Failed"})[15m:1m]) > 0
    for: 0m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: Kubernetes Pod not healthy (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "Pod has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.\n  V
```

or for [crash looping](https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html#rule-kubernetes-1-18):

> Pod {{ $labels.pod }} is crash looping

```yaml
  - alert: KubernetesPodCrashLooping
    expr: increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[1m]) > 3
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: Kubernetes pod crash looping (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "Pod {{ $labels.pod }} is crash looping\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
```

See also [this good guide about monitoring kubernetes cluster with Prometheus](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus/):

> The Kubernetes API and the  [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics)  (which natively uses prometheus metrics)  **solve part of this problem**  by exposing Kubernetes internal data, such as the number of desired / running replicas in a deployment, unschedulable nodes, etc.
>
> Prometheus is a good fit for microservices because you just need to  **expose a metrics port**, and don’t need to add too much complexity or run additional services. Often, the service itself is already presenting a HTTP interface, and the developer just needs to add an additional path like  `/metrics`.

If it comes to unschedulable nodes, you can use the metric `kube_node_spec_unschedulable`. It is described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/node-metrics.md) or [here](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring/):
`kube_node_spec_unschedulable` - Whether a node can schedule new pods or not.

Look also at [this guide](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-the-ultimate-guide-to-monitoring-resource-metrics).
Basically, you need to find the metric you want to monitor and set it appropriately in Prometheus. Alternatively, you can use templates, as I showed at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Thank You Sharing Answer.